# R Stata Generating an unbalanced panel data based on two variables

Tags: panel, reshape, transpose, reshape2, panel-data

I have a dataset with a structure similar to this sample:

[image: Before_data]

And I would like to turn it into a panel data based on the variables: "year" and "pol_party*", in order to have this:

[image: After_data]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done employing tidyr package (included in tidyverse) in R.

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
base <- base %>%
  gather(key = "pol_party_columns", value = "pol_party_values", pol_party1:pol_party4) %>%
  select(-pol_party_columns, pol_party = pol_party_values)
```

First off, you have to gather all the columns into two other columns. Then, you just have to remove the first and rename the second.